Which PayPal product should I use for a Shopify-like ecommerce platform?
I run a Shopify-like SaaS, and I need to be able to collect payments from my customers' customers on behalf of my customers.
It needs to support both one-time payments as well as subscriptions (+ webhooks).
I checked out https://developer.paypal.com, but it was so overwhelming; I had no idea what I needed just to integrate something on behalf of my customers.
I'd imagine I need something that allows me to perform actions using their PayPal accounts on behalf of my customers (e.g. via OAuth authorization).
What is the best PayPal product to get what I want to achieve?

There is a `multiparty` section to developer.paypal.com 's documentation, explore that. Subscriptions will be much more complicated to integrate than one-time payments, and how you do so will depend on whether you are using PayPal's subscription engine (fixed amounts on a fixed cycle, available to all business accounts) or vault/billing agreements for arbitrary amounts at arbitrary times (every receiving account must be approved for use)

Is multi-party the least complex option? I'm looking for the simplest option that would allow me to collect payments on behalf of my sellers.
